# Vibrational noise for scientific apparatus on a satellite

Tags: satellites, vibrations, noise

Say we're running an experiment on a satellite in *some* earth orbit.  For example, maybe we're imaging something with transmission electron microscope or we're catching atoms in ion traps --- really anything.

In practice, and otherwise keeping things very simple on the satellite to avoid mechanical / etc. noises, what kind of vibrational noise profile will we have relative to what's possible on earth?  What would be the primary cause of the main noise source (e.g. on earth this might be the building's ventilation system followed by geological sources, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the vibrations to be mindful of would include any type of propulsion, thrusters, etc, also any internal electrical motors, actuators, power supplies, etc.  Moreover, I would also think essentially anything electrical-related e.g. wiring, capacitors, etc since electrical parts are known to vibrate when current is passing through them.

I'm really just guessing but those are the types of vibration-inducing and hence distorting inducing objects that come to mind.